How do I create a list of category pills for a media blog?
Why isn't it possible for two media articles, created from a Django model (called MediaModule), who have two separate sets of categories?
I have a TextField which contains a list of related categories, separated by a comma. I just want to be able to list those categories in my Django template. Why do my articles keep getting the same categories despite having a  separate word list in my Django database?
models.py:
from django.db import models
import uuid, random, string

def generate_unique_id(charlimit):
    '''This will generate a random set of numbers and letters which will be used to generate a unique URL for each object in the model.
    '''
    random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=charlimit))  # Generates a random string
    return f"{random_string}"

def generate_unique_uuid():
    '''This will generate a random set of numbers and letters which are to be derrived from the UUID methodology, which will be used to generate a unique URL for each object in the model.
    '''
    return str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]

# Create your models here.
class MediaModule(models.Model):
    uuid                   =    models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    article_identifier     =    models.CharField(max_length=50, default=generate_unique_id(12), unique=True, editable=False)
    article_headline       =    models.CharField(max_length=100)
    article_body           =    models.TextField()
    article_synopsis       =    models.TextField(null=True)
    article_journalist     =    models.CharField(max_length=20)
    article_date           =    models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    article_image          =    models.ImageField(upload_to='assets')
    article_image_summary  =    models.TextField(default="", null=True, blank=True)
    article_image_credit   =    models.TextField(default="", null=True, blank=True)
    article_pills          =    models.TextField(default="News")

    def get_words_list(self):
        return [word.strip() for word in self.article_pills.split(',')]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_headline 

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import MediaModule
from blauwestadtech import utils

def article_objects():
  '''This will create an instance of the model to obtain all values from the model. It will then return the name of the model instance.s'''
  articles  =  MediaModule.objects.all()
  return articles

print(MediaModule.objects.all())

def article_list(request):
  '''This denotes the list of available articles and press releases'''
  articles                =   article_objects()
  meta_object__title        =   utils.meta_object__title("Press & Media")
  meta_object__narrative    =   utils.meta_object__narrative("Stay updated with our latest news and announcements on our Press and Media page. Access press releases, media contacts, and resources for journalists and media professionals.")
  meta_object__image        =   utils.meta_object__image()
  meta_object__url        =   utils.meta_object__url(request)
  template                =   loader.get_template('media-home.html')

  context   = {
     
    'articles'                : articles,
    'meta_object__title'          : meta_object__title,
    'meta_object__narrative'    :   meta_object__narrative,
    'meta_object__image'          : meta_object__image,
    'meta_object__url'        : meta_object__url

  } 

  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def details(request, article_identifier):
    
  articles                = article_objects()
  article                 = get_object_or_404(MediaModule,article_identifier=article_identifier)
  meta_object__title        = utils.meta_object__title(article.article_headline)
  meta_object__narrative    = utils.meta_object__narrative(article.article_synopsis)
  meta_object__image        = utils.meta_object__image(article.article_image.url)
  meta_object__url        = utils.meta_object__url(request)
  template                = loader.get_template('media-article.html')
  all_media_modules = MediaModule.objects.all()
  words_lists = [media_module.get_words_list() for media_module in all_media_modules]
      
  context = {
      
    'article'                 : article,
    'articles'                : articles,
    'meta_object__title'          : meta_object__title,
    'meta_object__narrative'    :   meta_object__narrative,
    'meta_object__image'          : meta_object__image,
    'meta_object__url'        : meta_object__url,
    'fruits'                  : ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry'],
    'words_lists'             : words_lists

    }

  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

media-article.html:
{% for words_list in words_lists %}
        <ul>
            {% for word in words_list %}
                <li>{{ word }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}

